# Meta Pixel / Google Tags, WordPress and HIPAA

Tags: php, wordpress, event-tracking, facebook-pixel

I'm thinking of switching from link clicks to conversion tracking for my advertising on Instagram and Google Ads, but I have concerns about the data both Meta and Google will collect, as I want to apply the event tracking to my sites registration form.

Is there a way to know and limit what data from the form they will have access to? I've read that a clinic violated HIPAA by using Meta pixel, and that's my concern as well. My site is HIPAA compliant.

My site is built on WordPress and uses Forminator for registration. I'm thinking of using the following code blocks:

```
/*Pixel Event Code*/
function fb_print_pixel_event(){
 if (is_page(46) ) : ?>

<!-- FB EVENT CODE HERE -->

 <?php endif; }

 add_action( 'wp_head', 'fb_print_pixel_event' );


/*Google Tag*/
<script>
jQuery('form#forminator-module-21').on('forminator:form:submit:success', function (e) { 
   ga('send', 'event', 'Form Title', 'submit');
 });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest putting the pixels on only the pages it needs. Which means not a master template that is used behind the registration.

Comment: Aynber, agreed. Any suggestions to limit what they can capture? I can’t afford to send them personal information of any kind. I don’t have any understanding of what their events codes can and can’t do.

Comment: I'm not sure. That goes a bit beyond me, but maybe keep it on the non-logged in pages. Having it on the registration/login page may break HIPAA since it may expose their email, but I'm not sure. I've added a few tags to your question that may help get more eyeballs.